# register and enqueue scripts after jquery doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I can't enqueue scripts after jquery so that the Dollar sign  ($) will be defined

I also tried to register and than enqueue, tried to put the scripts on footer (`wp_enqueue_script( 'name', 'url', '', true );`).
tried to hook it with `add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'xb_addScripts' );` and/or with `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xb_addScripts' );`
with or without version #.

```
    function xb_addScripts(){


//enqueue scripts
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xsite_a_js', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/xsite_a_js.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_ui', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/jqUI/jquery-ui.min.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'imgUpload', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/imgUpload.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );       
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xb_fGenerator', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/xb_fGenerator.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'xsite_date', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/xsite_dateObj.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_min', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js') , array('jquery'), '', false );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jq_ui_widget', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/jQuery-File-Upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js') , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );   
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jq_iframe_transport', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js') , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'file_upload', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/jQuery-File-Upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js') , array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );      


//enqueue styles
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_min', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css'),'','1','' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_theme_min', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'),'','1','' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'xsite_a_style', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/xsite_a_style.css'),'','1','' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'xb_form_style', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/join/xb_form_style.css'),'','1','' ); 
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jq_css', plugins_url('xSITE-crm/inc/jqUI/jquery-ui.min.css'),'','1','' );            
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> When you enqueue script that is dependent on jQuery, note that the jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode

Few ways around it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
//your stuff
});
```

or

```
var $j = jQuery;
$j('.my_class').show();
```

or

```
jQuery('.my_class').show();
```